# mac osx terminal : bad interpreter

Tags: python, macos, terminal, virtualenv

I have a directory structure that looks something like this :

```
env/
    bin/
        pip
        easy_install
        python
    include/
        ...
    lib/
        ...
```

when I run the command the command : `ls env/bin`
 
the terminal output is :
    `activate       easy_install-2.7    python2
    activate.csh        pip         python2.7
    activate.fish       pip2            wheel
    activate_this.py    pip2.7
    easy_install        python`

when I run the command : 
    `env/bin/python` the python interpreter fires up.
But when I run the command : `env/bin/pip` the terminal output is :
    `-bash: bin/pip: "/Users/ironstein/Documents/projects: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
I don't understand this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a space after `projects` in the name of one of your parent folders.  The shebang (`#!...`) line in `env/bin/pip` probably looks something like this:

`#!"/Users/ironstein/Documents/projects ..."`

which is an attempt to quote the path, but OS X doesn't support quoting spaces or any form of escaping in the shebang line.  You need to rename `projects ...` so it doesn't have spaces in it, and recreate your virtualenv.